# make a unified image out of many sprites in unity

Tags: unity, gui, unityscript

i made a customization character system that it has a seperate image UI for every part f body like eyes, hat, ears and...

now i want to make a unified texture out of it to be able to save it as an image file.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a second camera which would look at a copy of each of the UI elements making up the character on a background of your choice, make it render into a render texture and then blit that texture to a Unity Texture2D which has a method to [EncodeToPNG()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) on that page there's also a good example of how to use it for what you want.